# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' : Tomcat + MySQL + Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

For this question I found lot of given answers but unfortunately nothing worked for me. That's why I am posting the question. Your help would be highly appreciated.

My `Server.xml` in Tomcat under `apache-tomcat-7.0.69\conf` is as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/spring_hibernateDB"
  global="jdbc/spring_hibernateDB"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate"
  username="test"
  password="password"
  maxActive="100"
  maxIdle="20"
  minIdle="5"
  maxWait="10000"
  />
```

My `context.xml` under `apache-tomcat-7.0.69\conf` is as follows:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mySpring_hibernateDB"
    global="jdbc/spring_hibernateDB"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

My `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mySpring_hibernateDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My `Spring-servlet.xml` is as follows:

```
<bean id="jndiDSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" autowire="byName">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/mySpring_hibernateDB" />
</bean>

<bean id="mysessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="jndiDSource" p:mappingResources="employee.hbm.xml">

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And I have included mysql jar at bot in `tomcat/lib` and in eclipse `webapp/lib` forlder. when I am running the application I am getting the below error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:412)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.loadAll(HibernateTemplate.java:585)
    com.abdul.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.fetchAll(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:38)
    com.abdul.service.EmployeeService.fetchAllEmps(EmployeeService.java:27)
    com.abdul.controller.EmployeeController.displayAllEmps(EmployeeController.java:54)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1596)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$5.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:591)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$5.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:585)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:407)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:375)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.loadAll(HibernateTemplate.java:585)
    com.abdul.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.fetchAll(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:38)
    com.abdul.service.EmployeeService.fetchAllEmps(EmployeeService.java:27)
    com.abdul.controller.EmployeeController.displayAllEmps(EmployeeController.java:54)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because there is no driver or URL defined for the JndiDS

You need to have the JndiDs like:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> <!-- Define MySQL DB Driver name and URL -->
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate" />
    <property name="username" value="..." />
    <property name="password" value="..." />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="2" />
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

Check this example http://blog.zenika.com/2013/01/30/using-tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-in-a-standalone-environment/

You can use only the JNDI name, but you have to update the Hibernate properties

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/spring_hibernateDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Check http://www.journaldev.com/2905/hibernate-tomcat-jndi-datasource-example-tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In our scenario DB Credentials cannot be share with development team. we have to use only jndi name that is defined at the server. I have only jndi name. Can you please suggest any solution that uses only jndi name. In your code we have to know db username and password.

Comment: Even I use any other application server like Glassfish or JBoss then is it required to created data source like this? I mean should I specify the username and password?

Comment: Check the update.  You create a 'Resource' on Tomcat and reference it with Hibernate and use it as a DS in Spring.  DS can be referred to by JNDI name alone

Comment: Thanks for your update. I need to give a name for the session factory so that i can create HibernateTemplate in spring application. Can you please let me know how to do that. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please, post it as a new question.  Anytime

Comment: The updated answer is not resolved my problem. Your first answer I can accept. Please update your answer and then i will mark it as accepted. Thank you;